# FOSUserBundle issues with plainPassword on twig form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I am defining my own twig layout for new user registration and I have everything laid out the way I want it with the exception of the plainPassword field from the FOSUserBundle.

```
<p class="left">
   {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}
</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

The code above displays both the password and verification block.  I would like to break this up into the 4 elements of form.plainPassword.label, form.plainPassword.field, form.plainPassword2.label, and form.plainPassword2.field.  I cannot figure out what to put in the `form_label()` and `form_widget()` calls.

```
<p class="left">
   {{ form_label( ??? ) }}
   {{ form_widget( ??? ) }}
</p>
<p class="left">
   {{ form_label( ??? ) }}
   {{ form_widget( ??? ) }}
</p>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I am assuming this can be done.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. My solution (seems to be official :) :

```
{{ form_label (form.plainPassword.first) }}   
{{ form_widget (form.plainPassword.first) }}  

{{ form_label (form.plainPassword.second) }}   
{{ form_widget (form.plainPassword.second) }}
```

Hope it can helps !

Comment: @Comstar Consider accepting this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

This blog post shows how to output a repeated field in twig.

http://blogsh.de/2011/10/19/how-to-use-the-repeated-field-type-in-symfony/

But in short this worked for me:

```
{{ form_label (form.plainPassword.children['New Password']) }}   
{{ form_widget (form.plainPassword.children['New Password']) }}  

{{ form_label (form.plainPassword.children['Confirm Password']) }}   
{{ form_widget (form.plainPassword.children['Confirm Password']) }}
```

I have to say I'm sure using .children isnt the best/official way of doing it, but it works!

Comment: Worked for me with children['first'] and children['second'] (Symfony 2.1)